# Set xerces feature from command line or environment

Tags: xml, apache-fop, xerces

I use Apache FOP on the command line to transform xsl:fo files into pdf.

Those xsl:fo files contain `<!DOCTYPE []>` constructs that cause fatal errors:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/Y:/fo-files/Untitled.fo; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 10;
DOCTYPE is disallowed when the feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" set to true.
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:485)
        at org.apache.fop.cli.InputHandler.transformTo(InputHandler.java:293)
        at org.apache.fop.cli.InputHandler.renderTo(InputHandler.java:116)
        at org.apache.fop.cli.Main.startFOP(Main.java:186)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.fop.cli.Main.startFOPWithDynamicClasspath(Main.java:143)
        at org.apache.fop.cli.Main.main(Main.java:219)
```

It is necessary to set the xerces `"http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl"` feature to false.

How can I set that feature from FOP command line or from the environment (config, properties or else)?

Comment: The first google match is ["Setting features"](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/features.html). So you should set `reader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/disallow-doctype-decl", 
                      false);` I guess.

Comment: I know that. I wish there is a way to specify this from the outside, that is without creating a specific java program. (The reason is: I am asked an "off-the-self" solution. Adding java code to the project is out of question.) Now I will check if there is some way to have FOP call Alfred/Saxon instead of Xerces/Xalan. Saxon use a configuration file.

Comment: That's interesting, because in this link it is mentioned that `FALSE` is the default value. Therefore you shouldn't have had any problems with the standard configuration. So my remaining suggestion would be to create a simple Java STUB which sets the right parameters without changing any of your other programs. Good luck, anyway.